# Can not rewrite to file using .htaccess in CodeIgniter?

Tags: .htaccess, codeigniter

My structure like this :

```
- application
  - controllers
  - log
    - login
- mysite
```

I want to redirect `http://mysite/index.php/log/login` => `mysite/login.html`

I turned on Rewrite Mode; In my .htaccess:

```
Options +FollowSymLinks All -Indexes
RewriteEngine On
RewriteRule ^login.html$ ./index.php/log/login
```

but I met 404 error. I tested by make one file `test.php` and place it in `mysite` folder
=> It is OK!

Please help me config that URL.

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
Options -Indexes
RewriteEngine on  

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond $1 !^(index\.php)
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ index.php/log/$1 [L]
```